# Sort an array of numbers based on a given order

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays. The first array contains the sort order. The second array contains an arbitrary number of elements.

I have the property that all elements (value-wise) from the second array are guaranteed to be in the first array, and I am only working with numbers.

```
A = [1,3,4,4,4,5,2,1,1,1,3,3]
Order = [3,1,2,4,5]
```

When I sort `A`, I would like the elements to appear in the order specified by `Order`:

```
[3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```

Note that duplicates are fair game. The elements in A should not be altered, only re-ordered. How can I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't start your variable names with capital letters, as then they become constants. Also, are there no values in `A` other than those in `Order`?

Comment: For this particular case, yes, there are no other values. If some array originally did have other values they would be filtered out before coming to this sort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>> source = [1,3,4,4,4,5,2,1,1,1,3,3]
=> [1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
>> target = [3,1,2,4,5]
=> [3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
>> source.sort_by { |i| target.index(i) }
=> [3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```

Comment: @MichaelKohl you made a good point that if this array is likely to get big then the approach could probably be reconsidered, but this should be fast enough for most purposes

Answer (score 4):

If (and only if!) @Gareth's answer turns out to be too slow, instead go with:

```
# Pre-create a hash mapping value to index once only…
index = Hash[ Order.map.with_index.to_a ] #=> {3=>0,1=>1,2=>2,4=>3,5=>4}

# …and then sort using this constant-lookup-time
sorted = A.sort_by{ |o| index[o] }
```

---

Benchmarked:

```
require 'benchmark'

order = (1..50).to_a.shuffle
items = 1000.times.map{ order.sample }
index = Hash[ order.map.with_index.to_a ]

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  N = 10_000
  x.report("Array#index"){ N.times{
    items.sort_by{ |n| order.index(n) }
  }}
  x.report("Premade Hash"){ N.times{
    items.sort_by{ |n| index[n] }
  }}
  x.report("Hash on Demand"){ N.times{
    index = Hash[ order.map.with_index.to_a ]
    items.sort_by{ |n| index[n] }
  }}
end

#=>                      user     system      total        real
#=> Array#index     12.690000   0.010000  12.700000 ( 12.704664)
#=> Premade Hash     4.140000   0.000000   4.140000 (  4.141629)
#=> Hash on Demand   4.320000   0.000000   4.320000 (  4.323060)
```

Comment: `#sort_by` already internally generates a temporary array of mapping values - is this Hash cache more efficient than the array of tuples [referred to in the documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by)?

Comment: @Gareth Yes, because for _n_ values in an array of size _m_ using `Array#index` requires on average _n*m/2_ operations (worst case: _n*m_), while using the hash lookup always uses just _m_ operations (or _n+m_ for the case where you're including the hashing time in the calculation). Moreover, the _n_ for `index` has to take place in slow Ruby land, while the _n_ with the hash preparation takes place almost entirely in C. See my edit.

Comment: @Gareth But, as you said in your comment, your answer will probably be "fast enough" most of the time. For example, sorting an array of 50 items with one of 10 values is about 30µs using your way and 15-20µs my way. :)

Comment: Oh of course. I was only looking at the Hash you were building, and ignoring the way you weren't using `Array#index`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution without explicit sorting:

```
source = [1,3,4,4,4,5,2,1,1,1,3,3]
target = [3,1,2,4,5]
source.group_by(&lambda{ |x| x }).values_at(*target).flatten(1)
```